# Generate a link to Stripe Customer Account Link regardless of the current browser account

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe in Django, I would like to generate a navigation link from django admin portal to  Stripe Customer Account.

eg:

[Customer Id]

[image: 1]

I've concatenated the id to the following url: "https://dashboard.stripe.com/customers/"
to be "https://dashboard.stripe.com/customers/cus_LX88WdbprptpWe"

If I click the link, supposedly it opens the Stripe Account and navigates to the customer, this is incase the customer exists in this account. While if the customer actually exists, but currently in the browser I'm logged on a different stripe account, the customer response will not be found.

eg:

[Customer not found]

[image: 2]

What I wonder is how to generate a valid stripe customer account link that redirects to the customer's account as well as the correct Stripe Account to avoid the "not found customer" issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not available, if you have a compelling use for this functionality then I would recommend writing in to the Stripe support team to see if it is something that they'd be interested in building.
https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true